# How to install the IBM Worklight Developer Edition on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ibm-mobilefirst

everyone could any one help me out with "How can install the IBM Worklight Developer Edition on Android Studio.
I have seen so much links and video which works with Eclipse but i didnt find any plugin which could attach with android Studio.
Thanks in advance. your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are not supposed to install it on Android Studio.

The MobileFirst Studio plug-in is a plug-in for *Eclipse*.
You need to install the plug-in in Eclipse as well as create your project in Eclipse using the plug-in.

You can then build the project, in Eclipse, and open it in Android Studio for further development.

Comment: so are you saying ibm worklight does not supprt Android studio IDE?

Comment: Read again. I said you need to build (generate) the project in Eclipse and you can then open the Android project in Android Studio.